# Set Curssor in side TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to set the curssor in side the text view.my curssor is blinking outside of textview.

I am using xml code in android.

```
 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/et_uname"
   android:layout_width="150dip"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:gravity="fill_vertical"
   android:background="@drawable/textviewstyle" />
```

Comment: textView.setSelection(getText().length()); may work

Comment: avoid using hard coding in your layout.That makes it more compatible on different devices. Share the complete XML if possible

Answer (score 1):

```
et_username.setText("Updated Text From another Activity");
int position = et_username.length();
Editable etext = et_username.getText();
Selection.setSelection(etext, position);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Java Activity

```
EditText et_username;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_uname);
    int position = et_username.getText().toString().length/2;
    et_username.setSelection(position);
}
```

Comment: I am trying but its not working.i want to display the cursor in side of text box.

Comment: just tell me please what do you want exactly, Do you want to put the cursor in the middle of text into an edittext when you finish typing or when you press a button or what?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Friend To your help i got answer.and also i got simple way and i want to share with all.

```
 <EditText
                 android:id="@+id/et_uname"
                 android:layout_width="150dip"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/textviewstyle" 
                 android:paddingLeft="3dp"/>
```

Through android:paddingLeft we can set the cursor.